# How to use google map in Flutter web or Flutter Windows?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps

Is it possible for Google Map to be implemented in the Flutter Web and FLutter Desktop (Windows)? Because the flutter_google_maps plugin doesnt support desktop and web, how to implement it?